# What does *I mean in sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy

```
pip install sympy

import math as m
from sympy import *

a,b = symbols('a b')
x1, y1 = (2, m.radians(152.6))
x2, y2 = (4, m.radians(163.7))

result = solve((a*sin(b*x1)-y1, a*sin(b*x2)-y2), dict=True)
print(result)
```

result is like below

[{a: -3.15571732546928 + 1.66055281406852e-26*I, b: -0.502333320617012 + 2.31610571514848e-22*I}, {a: -3.15571732546928 + 1.66055281406852e-26*I, b: 2.63925933297278 + 2.24993126614424e-22*I}, {a: 3.15571732546928 + 1.66055281406852e-26*I, b: -2.63925933297278 + 2.24993126614424e-22*I}, {a: 3.15571732546928 + 1.66055281406852e-26*I, b: 0.502333320617012 + 2.31610571514848e-22*I}]

What does this number mean?, especially 'e-26*I'

Comment: Note that using floats in sympy isn't recommended, as sympy's goal is looking for exact symbolic solutions. Other libraries (numpy, scipy) are more suitable. If possible, try to avoid float values and the `math` library in combination with sympy.  If you already have other code using sympy, and you want to keep the same syntax, `nsolve` can look for numeric solutions.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
If possible, can you introduce a code that uses numpy to find the values ​​of “a, b” by substituting some x and y values ​​for y = a*sin(b*x) ?

Answer (score 1):

`I`, in Sympy, is the imaginary number constant. That is, the number defined to be the square root of negative one. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)

> [A] complex number is an element of a number system that extends the real numbers with a specific element denoted `i`

In your case, Sympy has found complex-valued solutions to your trigonometry equation. It's possible to apply trigonometric functions to complex numbers, and indeed often the only solution to an equation like that is a complex number.

The `e` part is a common format for displaying numbers in computer terminals. It's similar to [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). The number `3e+8` should be read as three times ten to the eighth power. Likewise, `2e-1` should be read as two times ten to the negative-first power, or `0.2`.

So, to take your first example,

```
-3.15571732546928 + 1.66055281406852e-26I
```

This is a complex number whose real part is `-3.1557` and whose imaginary part is, frankly, a really small number (a decimal point followed by 25 zeroes and then some nonzero quantities).

What this likely means is that Sympy could *not* algebraically solve the equation, so it resorted to some numerical methods which could only get close. It's possible `a = -pi` is a solution, since `-3.155` is pretty close to pi and the imaginary part of that number might as well be zero.

Comment: Thank you. I also drew a graph from your answer and got a good solution.